# top ten in ten minutes - hive query

Tags: hive, hql

I have to calculate ten most visited sites in for each 5 min interval since 00:00:00
Given below is my data:

```
  time     site
00:00:00    google.com
00:01:06    yahoo.com
00:03:06    youtube.com
00:05:09    google.com
00:11:07    amazon.com
00:14:05    yahoo.com
00:21:00    google.com
00:30:56    amazon.com
```

I am confused to use the multiple queries as part of the single hive query.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

**Query**:

```
select interv, col2, count(col2)
from (
  select floor((unix_timestamp(col1)-unix_timestamp(to_date(col1),'yyyy-MM-dd'))/600)*600 as interv, col1, col2  
  from default.test_time_group) t
group by interv,col2;
```

**Sample schema**:

```
{time TIMESTAMP, site STRING}
```

**Example:**

```
2015-10-07 00:00:00    google.com
2015-10-07 00:01:06    yahoo.com
```

**Result**:

```
interval  col2         count

0         google.com   2
0         yahoo.com    1
0         youtube.com  1
600       amazon.com   1
600       yahoo.com    1
1200      google.com   1
1800      amazon.com   1
```

**Explanation**:  I subtracted the unix timestamp of column date from unix timestamp of date (without timestamp) to check the interval.  To get all 10 minutes transactions in the same interval I divided by 600, took the `floor()`, and multiply by 600.  Then I grouped by interval and col2 to get the results.

Note: You can set sorting as per your needs.